# What area does the antiderivative represent?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Consider the antiderivative of the function $e^{-x},$ which is $-e^{-x}.$ Evaluating the antiderivative at the value $0$ produces $-1.$

I was taught to conceptualize an antiderivative as an area under a curve, or a sum of progressively smaller approximate sections.

But clearly, $-1$ cannot represent the area under under the $e^{-x}$ curve from $0$ to $0$, $0$ to $\infty$, or $-\infty$ to $0$ when you consider that the function is positive for all values of $x$.

Then what sum or area does the value of the antiderivative of $e^{-x}$ actually represent?

Comment: There is no *the* antiderivative of $e^{-x}$. Every function of the form $-e^{-x} + C$ is *an* antiderivative of $e^{-x}$. Secondly, a connection between antiderivatives and areas is given by the fundamental theorem of calculus surely, but strictly speaking, it’s *definite* integrals that should be thought of as an area, not *indefinite* integrals.

Comment: For $0 \leq a < b,$ you have that $$~\int_a^b e^{-x}~dx = \left[-e^{-x}\right]_{x=a}^{x=b} = e^{-a} - e^{-b}.$$

Comment: Don’t forget that it would just solve $y’=e^x$. Also see:$y’(x,y)=e^{x+y}\implies y=e^{x+y}+f(y)+c$

Answer (score 3):

> Evaluating the antiderivative at the value $0$ produces $-1$. Now, I was taught to conceptualize an antiderivative as an area under a curve

1. For $t>a,$ the signed area (i.e., the area in the positive vertical region minus the area in the negative vertical region) $A(t)$ enclosed by the curve $y=f(x),$ the $x$-axis, and the vertical lines at $a$ and $t$ is denoted by the **(definite) integral** $$\int_a^tf(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$ whose elongated-S symbol stands for Sum (of areas).
2. If $f$ is continuous on $[a,t],$ then the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that this integral is computable using the formula $$\int_a^tf(x)\,\mathrm dx=F(t)-F(a),\tag1$$ where $F$ is *an* **antiderivative** of $f,$ that is, any of the infinitely many functions whose derivative (slope function) is $f.$ Therefore, if $f$ is continuous on $[a,t],$ then $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_a^tf(x)\,\mathrm dx=f(t).\tag2$$ Rewriting $(1):$ if $F$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,t],$ then $$\int_a^t\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F(x)\,\mathrm dx=F(t)-F(a).\tag1$$
3. The **indefinite integral** $$\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ represents *every* antiderivative of $f,$ if any. For example, \begin{align}\int \frac1x\,\mathrm dx &= \begin{cases} \ln|x|+C_1, &x<0;\\   
       \ln|x|+C_2, &x>0.\end{cases}\end{align}

   [Conceptually](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/2364/372), **an indefinite integral is not technically the precursor of a definite integral**: for example,
   for \begin{align}g(x)&= \begin{cases} 2x\sin\frac1{x^3}-\frac3{x^2}\cos\frac1{x^3}, &x\ne0;\\   
       0, &x=0,\end{cases}\end{align} $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 g(x)\,\mathrm dx$ does not exist even as \begin{align}\int g(x)\,\mathrm dx&= \begin{cases} x^2\sin\frac1{x^3}&+C, &x\ne0;\\   
       0&+C, &x=0,\end{cases}\end{align} that is, even as $g$ does have antiderivatives on $[-1,1].$
4. Since antidifferentiation and indefinite integration literally reverse differentiation, they *don't need to be specified on an interval*.

   On the other hand, definite integration is a computation *with reference to some interval*.

   The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus ($(1)$ & $(2)$ above) shows the surprising intimate relationship between definite integration and differentiation.
5. An antiderivative per se does not describe area, and $F_λ(0)=-1$ means that *a particular function* whose slope is given by $f$ passes through $(0,-1).$

   Clearly, a single value of an antiderivative is not useful information; the FTC's power comes from making its two evaluations using the *same* antiderivative of $f:$ $$\int_a^tf(x)\,\mathrm dx=F_λ(t)-F_λ(a)\\\neq F_λ(t)-F_ω(a).$$
6. A pertinent [comment](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/a-different-symbol-for-the-indefinite-integral-antiderivative?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment43529_17051) by B. Sullivan:

   > I just finished reading Steven Strogatz's new book about calculus, Infinite Powers. In it, he lays out the "Three Central Problems of Calculus":
   >
   > 1. Given a curve, find its slope everywhere. [**differentiation**]
   > 2. Given a curve, find another curve whose slope everywhere is that given curve. [**antidifferentiation**]
   > 3. Given a curve, find the area under it. [**(definite) integration**]
7. The **actual area** enclosed by $y=f(x),$ the $x$-axis, and
   the vertical lines at $a$ and $t$ is $$\int_a^t|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx,$$ which does not generally equal $F(t)-F(a).$

Comment: [Integration and antiderivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4637673/21813)