# what is the pure meaning of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

When I began with integration I learned that the definite integral is the area under a given curve but when I studied the definite integral further I learned about Riemann sum and the limit of Riemann sum is the definite integral and it's the area under the curve.

But what confuses me that there are some definite integrals which gives a negative value and also there is an improper integral,How these integrals can be thought of as area?,How can a negative area exist ?

I don't think  that the definite integral (which is equal to Riemann sum ) is the area under a curve, it can be used to calculate the area but it's meaning not the area under a curve

Can someone explain explicitly what is the correct and the pure mathematical meaning to the definite integral.

Comment: The area isn’t negative. But a definite integral can be negative. The key is this: the definite integral is the sum of the areas above the x-axis minus the sum of the areas below the x-axis.

Comment: @AdamRubinson 
I know that but does the pure meaning of integration is the area under the curve ??

Comment: In my opinion "improper integral" is just a bad name. I think that the better name to use is "antiderivative", since what it actually is is just that, a function which when differentiated gives you your original function. The reason the word "integral" is used is because there's a connection between integrals and derivatives given by the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) where it's stated that antiderivatives can be used to evaluate definite integrals.

Comment: @RobertLee 
but what is the pure meaning of the integration ?

Comment: @amin, Adam Rubinson's definition is as pure of a definition as I can think of. The definite integral is the area between the curve and the $x$-axis when the curve is above the $x$-axis, minus the area between the curve and the $x$-axis when the curve is below the $x$-axis.

Comment: [Meaning of integration and antidifferentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283261/21813)

Comment: @ryang 
but according to your answer the definite integral is no more than the summation of the signed area , but in any real analysis book the definition of integral according to rimmean sum is that \begin{gather} \lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})\Delta x_{i}=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \end{gather} 

and the area is defined according to the integral definition not the other way around

Comment: @ryang 
i mean that the integral defines the area not the other way around,if we thought of integrals as the area under the curve only then we limit our understanding to rimmean sum definiton

Comment: @amin Both our linked answers and both our above comments give the same answer to your question, "what is the ("pure"?) meaning of integration?" You seem to be contesting them (your comments are incoherent: I don't know what you mean by "A defines B"; A=B and B=A mean the same, and I'm not sure what specifically you're apparently objecting to) without any concrete position, so what reply should you expect. Anyway, my linked answer (which neither contains nor suggests the phrase "no more than") merely outlines various adjacent perspectives to help contextualise understanding.