# Is this integral negative?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I was learning integration in Calculus when I thought of using this in different fields where it can be useful. Just for a sample case, I am defining $f(x)$ to be a piecewise function:
$$
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x, & x \leq 0 \\
            \infty, & 0 < x < 2 \\
            1, & x \geq 2
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
$$
When I integrate $f(x)$ from 1 to 2 I would get something like this
$$
\int_1^2f(x) \\
= 1*2-\infty*1 \\
= 2-\infty
$$
I did this by the constant rule in Integration where $\int{a} dx=ax+C$ and this rule, $\int_a^b{f(x)}dx=F(b)-F(a)$ where $F$ is the antiderivative of the function $f$.
$2-\infty$ would definitely be $-\infty$ which is negative integral, but this confuses me as we have positive values from 1 to 2, and in this case a negative integral does not make sense. Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: Ordinarily $f(x) = \infty$ is not considered a function, and you can't really multiply and subtract infinity like that. There are extended number systems that attempt to deal with infinity as a number, but they require care since many "basic facts" of algebra are no longer true.

Comment: How do you get the $1 \times 2$ piece?

Comment: By the antiderivative of a constant rule

Comment: I edited the $x>2$ to $x\geq2$. But even after that, I have seen some sites show antiderivative of infinity to be infinity times x. Is that wrong?

Comment: If you replace $\infty$ with some constant $c$, then you have a perfectly reasonable function. You can then reason in terms of that version, and in particular consider whether the limit $c\to\infty$ makes any sense in this context.

Comment: So am I getting the limit's value here, which is different compared to the correct integral value? And if yes, is it something defined or indeterminate?

Comment: The real integral's value

Comment: I find everything here hard to follow. Even if you treat $\infty$ like a constant for whatever reason, it still doesn't make sense how you got $1 \cdot 2 - \infty \cdot 1$ through FTC.

Comment: I split the integral into difference of two antiderivatives. $F(2)=2+C$ and (next part is according to my understanding) anti derivative of infinity is infinity times x (just because I treated infinity as a constant), thus $F(1)=\infty*1+C$. And since this is a piecewise function and the breakpoints are at 0 and 2, finding the value of this definite integral will be fine. I just now have the doubt about the infinity case. I may be wrong at the infinity's antiderivative part.

Comment: That's not how integrals work. You don't combine indefinite integrals and definite integrals like that. If you are trying to evaluate $\int_1^2 f(x)dx$ based on how you defined your piecewise function, it won't make sense because $\infty$ is usually not considered a function.

Comment: 1. Even if we replace the ill-defined $\infty$ with $100,$ as in aschepler's answer below, it is impossible to construct an antiderivative of $f$ that is even differentiable at $0$ and $2$ respectively, due to the sharp turns there even if the antiderivative is continuous there. $\quad$ 2. Since $f$ isn't defined on [1,2), that definite integration rule that you cite is invalid on $[1,2].$

Comment: 3. Furthermore, since the domain of $f$ is not an interval, that $\int\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=f(x)+C$ rule that you cite is also not generally applicable to $f.\quad$ 4. You might find [this outline](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283261/21813) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the infinity questions, I'll use a large constant $100$ instead:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \leq 0 \\ 100 & 0 < x < 2 \\ 1 & x \geq 2 \end{cases} $$

The trouble with this function is it does not have an antiderivative. If we try piecewise derivatives like

$$ F(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} x^2 + C_1 & x\leq 0 \\ 100x + C_2 & 0 < x < 2 \\ x + C_3 & x \geq 2 \end{cases} $$

then there are no choices for $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$ which make $F$ differentiable at $2$. A function must be continuous to be differentiable, so we would need $200+C_2=2+C_3$. But then

$$ F'(2) \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(2+h)-F(2)}{h} $$
but
$$ \lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{F(2+h)-F(2)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{(100h + 200 + C_2) - (2+C_3)}{h} = 100 $$
$$ \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{F(2+h)-F(2)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{(2+h+C_3)-(2+C_3)}{h} = 1 $$
so $F$ is not differentiable at $2$.

Instead, to take the integral of a piecewise function, we need to split it into multiple integrals on intervals where the function does have antiderivatives. For example,

$$ \begin{align*} \int_{-4}^4 f(x)\, dx &= \int_{-4}^0 f(x)\, dx + \int_0^2 f(x)\, dx + \int_2^4 f(x)\, dx \\
&= \int_{-4}^0 x\, dx + \int_0^2 100\, dx + \int_2^4 1\, dx \\
 &= \left(0-\frac{4^2}{2}\right) + (200-0) + (4-2) = 210 \end{align*} $$

For the integral from $0$ to $2$, which is also a piece of the example above, only the $f(x) = 100$ piece matters. It's actually an improper integral, which with discontinuities at the two endpoints must be evaluated like

$$ \int_{0}^2 f(x)\, dx = \lim_{\substack{a \to 0^+ \\ b \to 2^-}} \int_a^b f(x)\, dx $$