# Is representing indefinite integration as definite integration with the independent variable accurate?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Say we want to indefinitely integrate the function $f(x) = x^2$.

The usual way I would do it would be indefinite integration:

$
\int{dxf(x)}
=\int{dx^2}
=\frac{1}{3}x^3 + C
$

However, I've seen a few people do it a different (interesting) way, using definite integration, which is:

$
\int_{0}^{x}{dtf(t)}
=\int_{0}^{x}{dtt^2}
=[\frac{1}{3}t^3 + C]^{x}_{0}
=(\frac{1}{3}(x)^3 + C) - (\frac{1}{3}(0)^3 + C)
=\frac{1}{3}x^3
$

Abstractly, the second method sort of makes sense to work. The problem I have here is that the integration constant has been lost in the second method. Where have I made an incorrect assumption with the second method?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{x}{dxf(x)}$ (better written as $\int_{0}^{x}{dtf(t)}$ !) is a *definite* integral, that's why you don't get an integration constant.

Comment: It is good that $C$ cancles out , otherwise the value of the integral would depend on the chosen antiderivate. The integral in the last line is also called integral-function giving a special antiderivate with the property $F(0)=0$

Comment: You can just write something like $\int_0^xdt f(t)  + C$ to give an indefinite integral

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Say we want to indefinitely integrate the function $f(x) = x^2$. I've seen a few people do it using definite integration: \begin{align} \int_{0}^{x}{f(t)}\,\mathrm dt
>  =\int_{0}^{x}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt\\
>  =[\frac{1}{3}t^3 + C]^{x}_{0}\tag1\\
>  =(\frac{1}{3}(x)^3 + C) - (\frac{1}{3}(0)^3 + C)
>  =\frac{1}{3}x^3 \end{align} The problem
> I have here is that the integration constant has been lost

1. It's not that the parameter $C$ was lost but that it should never have been there in step $(1),$ which is invoking [the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283261/21813), which technically asks for *a particular antiderivative* (that is, an indefinite integral whose $C$ has been instantiated with a value—typically $0$ but any value is fine) to be plugged in.
2. Since an **indefinite integral** is the general specification of its integrand's infinitely many antiderivatives, instantiating an indefinite integral simply returns one of the antiderivatives. Instantiating an indefinite integral does not create a **definite integral**: the latter denotes a signed area that varies with the inputs $a$ and $b,$ whereas the former, and every antiderivative, varies with the input $x.$
3. Why does $\displaystyle∫^x_0f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ not contain the parameter $C?$

   As this object is literally a definite integral (albeit now varying with only $x$ rather than $a$ and $b$), it contains no arbitrary constant $C.$

   Simultaneously, if its integrand $f$ is continuous on $[0,x],$ then, by [the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283261/21813), this object is an (one particular) antiderivative of $f,$ which makes it not a family of functions, that is, not an indefinite integral. To be clear: an **antiderivative** of a function $f$ is literally a function whose derivative is $f,$ and the FTC says that $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=f(x).$
4. This point will be initially confusing, but ultimately illuminating: a definite integral isn't technically a particular instance of an indefinite integral: for example, for \begin{align}f(x)&= \begin{cases} 0, &x\in[-1,0)\cup(0,1];\\ 1, &x=0,\end{cases}\end{align}$\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$ even while $f$ has no antiderivative and so no indefinite integral.
5. > Say we want to indefinitely integrate the function $f(x) = x^2$. I've seen a few people do it using definite integration

   To “indefinitely integrate” $f$ (that is, to **antidifferentiate** $f$) by (definite-)integrating $f$ is actually being circular: you would be antidifferentiating $f$ by (definite-)integrating $f$ by applying the FTC by antidifferentiating $f.$

Answer (score 4):

$\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ gives you an antiderivative for any constant $a$, and different choices of $a$ correspond to different values of $C$.